# Meteor Aldeed - Collection2 - get length of an array field to use in autoValue

Tags: mongodb, meteor, collections, meteor-collection2

Hi all I'm using [Collection2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2) in my project and I want to get the length of a field which is of type: Array from another field

Here's my Code example

```
        yes: {
            type: Array,
            optional: true
        },
        "yes.$": {
            type: Object
        },
        yesLength: {
            type: Number,
            autoValue: function(){
                var lenYes = this.field("yes").length;
                console.log(this.field("yes"));
                console.log(lenYes)
                return lenYes;
            },
            optional: false
        },
```

when i log this.field("yes") to the console, it appears fine, but when I log lenYes i.e. this.field("yes").length, i get undefined. Am I doing something wrong here? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Collection2 you can only get the value of other fields *if they are `$set` in the modifier*. This is often not the case in which case you need to actually `.findOne()` to get the document and then get the current value out of it.

You can think of Collection2 as a validator for *changes* but it's not a validator for *current values*.

Since your `yesLength` is supposed to represent the length of an array and the length of an array can be changed in many unpredictable ways by a modifier it may make more sense to use a [collection hook](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks) to compute the `yesLength` *after* updates.

```
MyCollection.after.insert(function(userId,doc){
  if ( doc.yes ){ // the yes array exists
    MyCollection.direct.update(doc._id,{ $set: { yesLength: doc.yes.length }});
  }
});

MyCollection.after.update(function(userId,doc,fieldNames){
  if ( fieldNames.indexOf('yes') > -1 ) { // yes array was modified
    MyCollection.direct.update(doc._id,{ $set: { yesLength: doc.yes.length }});
  }
});
```

You need to use `.direct` to avoid reentering your hooks when you update the counter.

Comment: Thanks @michelFloyd. I there a way around what I want to achieve. I want the yesLength field to have the value set to the length of the "yes" field which is an array

Comment: Hi, Thanks but i got this error in my console _Exception while invoking method '/questions/update' Error: After filtering out keys not in the schema, your modifier is now empty_ whenever i tried updating or inserting my collection

Comment: That means you're doing an update with fields that are not in your schema. You probably removed `yesLength` from the schema altogether. Leave it in as type `Number`.

Comment: Thanks a lot **Michel Floyd**. I wirked fine